# Reacting to LiveData change within same ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have a base `ViewModel` extended by other `ViewModel`s:

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    protected val _state = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    protected val state: LiveData<Boolean> = _state 

    ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to react (for instance, add a log statement) whenever `state` changes (either `_state.setValue(newvalue)` or `_state.postValue(newvalue)` is called) and I'd like to do it inside the `BaseViewModel`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then

```
protected val state: LiveData<Boolean> = _state
```

The `state` should actually be a `MediatorLiveData` which registers `_state` as its source.

```
final MediatorLiveData<T> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();
mediator.addSource(_state, new Observer<T>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable T data) {
        // log here
        mediator.postValue(data);
    }
});
return mediator;
```

So in your case, it should be as such:

```
protected val state: LiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData().also { mediator ->
    mediator.addSource(_state) { data ->
        // log here
        mediator.postValue(data)
    }
}
```